# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" for file_exists call

Tags: php, syntax-error, file-exists

I'm using the following code to determine if a file is present in the directory pdf_Order_pdf/   which will display a working link or just and anchor link if file not present, I am a complete novice with php (as you can see) but do have a very limited understanding.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('pdf_Order_pdf/'.$row_Recordset1["our_ref"]'.pdf')) 
    echo 'pdf_Order_pdf/'.$row_Recordset1["our_ref"]'.pdf'; 
else 
    echo '#';
?>
```

the code above is in between the following html:

```
<a href="****code above ****">File</a>
```

I get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwiftPHP\resultsSupplier.php on line 230
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `.` operator after `$row_Recordset1["our_ref"]`

```
if(file_exists('pdf_Order_pdf/'.$row_Recordset1["our_ref"].'.pdf')) 
----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(file_exists('pdf_Order_pdf/'.$row_Recordset1["our_ref"].'.pdf')) 
                                                          ^dot here
```